# Before I enter the review queues, please evaluate this Q&A combo

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic-definition, specific-answer

I'm five points short of entering the review queues.  I'm practiced in other SE communities, but I'd like a bit of insight before I begin to review.

Please consider both this question and my answer to it: [Junior Developer Left to Own Devices](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/125536/junior-developer-left-to-own-devices/125544#125544)

As I thought about it after posting the answer, it seemed that "sharing wisdom" in a general sense isn't really what this site is about.  I re-read the Help Center pages about on-topic questions, and believe I should not have answered, but instead should have flagged the question as "off-topic: Questions require a goal that we can address."

Should I have avoided the answer and flagged the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, sharing wisdom *is* what this site is about.  However, the wisdom we share needs to address a general question as well as the specific.  The reasons for being off-topic are wrapped around the lack of a general answer or if it becomes a legal or company-specific issue, or there are too many possible answers (too broad, opinion-based).

As at the time of writing, there is only one close vote on the question and four upvotes, which seems to indicate the community sees it as being on-topic.

To that end, answer away!  But make sure that your answer isn't entirely anecdotal, it needs to be able to be backed up in some way with generally accepted wisdom or references.

That's not to say that anecdotal evidence isn't useful, but it needs to be written in the context of wider understanding.